# Git can't switch branch, stash or checkout

Tags: git

I try to switch branch from master to dev

```
git checkout dev
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by 
checkout:
    vendor/symfony/console/Resources/bin/hiddeninput.exe
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch 
branches.
Aborting
```

I try to remove the changes

```
git checkout vendor/symfony/console/Resources/bin/hiddeninput.exe
git checkout dev
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
vendor/symfony/console/Resources/bin/hiddeninput.exe
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

I try to stash

```
git stash
    error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
vendor/symfony/console/Resources/bin/hiddeninput.exe
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

I try ignoring it

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged vendor/symfony/console/Resources/bin/hiddeninput.exe
git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
git checkout dev
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
vendor/symfony/console/Resources/bin/hiddeninput.exe
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: A likely reason is that the file is tracked in one branch, but not the other.

Comment: Is `hiddeninput.exe` running?

Comment: Nope not running, nothing should be changing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across a similar issue a while back. Turns out that files have their end of line changed automatically (caused by mixed line endings in a file). This can be verified using-

```
git config core.autocrlf
```

In order to fix this, set core.autocrlf to false.

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Try doing git checkout your-filename after this. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems this combined with 
git config core.fileMode false did the trick.

Comment: This is great stuff. Thanks to you two, it had bothered me since weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Frist, `add` the changes (`statged` now) then do `stash`:

```
$ git add -A          # stage the changes
$ git stash           
$ git checkout dev
```

Or, you can do `hard reset` your HEAD then try checkout:

```
$ git add -A
$ git reset --hard HEAD
$ git checkout dev
```